# Persist an object within an object with jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jboss

I have this object

```
@Entity
public class Cat {
  @Id String name;
  Fur fur;
}

public class Fur {
  String color1;
  String color2;
}
```

How do I map it to:

```
 Name      Color1 Color2
+---------+------+------+
|SnowBall |red   |green |
+---------+------+------+
|Snowball2|white |black |
+---------+------+------+
```

I only have JPA 2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded` JPA annotations.

```
@Entity
public class Cat {
  @Id String name;
  @Embedded
  Fur fur;
}

@Embeddable
public class Fur {
  String color1;
  String color2;
}
```

Comment: I will have a look at that.